# Solution Explorer Filters in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, filter, projects-and-solutions

I'm looking for syntax information on the new Visual Studio 2010 .vcxproj.filters file. Is there a way to do wildcard filtering based on more than just the extension?

Here's the scenario:

We have a tool that writes a project file for Visual Studio 2005 defining all the messages in an application, along with the associated generated classes. In the project file, we grouped the C++ files not only by h/cpp, but also by user-defined filters, so our project might look something like this:

- messages      `( <-- that's the .vcproj file)`

  - GENERATED_MSGS

    - COM

      - h

        - COMRequest.h
        - COMRequestAck.h
      - cpp

        - COMRequest.cpp
        - COMRequestAck.cpp
    - DATA

      - h

        - DATARequest.h
        - DATARequestAck.h
      - cpp

        - DATARequest.cpp
        - DATARequestAck.cpp
    - ORDER

      - h
      - cpp
  - Header Files

    - HandCraftedMessage1.h
    - HandCraftedMessage2.h
  - Source Files

    - HandCraftedMessage1.cpp
    - HandCraftedMessage2.cpp
  - MyFileThatDefinesTheMessages.xml

The filters (COM, DATA, ORDER, etc.) are stored in the .vcproj file:

```
...
<Files>
    <Filter Name="GENERATED_MSGS">
        <Filter Name="COM">
            <Filter Name="COM">
                <Filter Name="h">
                    <File RelativePath=".\COMRequest.h"/>
...
```

In Visual Studio 2010, the files defined for the project are in the .vcxproj file, but the filters for how to display them are stored in the .vcxproj.filters file. Since our filters are always determined by the first part of the class name, I was hoping to get away with only creating the .vcxproj file with message generation tool and modifying the .filters file to use wildcards to put the files in the correct filter. For instance, a file named `ORDERRequest.h` should go into the `GENERATED_MSGS/ORDER/h` filter. Is there a way I can define a wildcard to do this, so that ORDER*.h would go in one folder, while COM*.h would go in a different folder? I have run across the `<Extensions>cpp;c;cc;cxx;def;odl;idl;hpj;bat;asm;asmx</Extensions>` tag, but this is not flexible enough for me, since I want to break it down more than just by extension.

Comment: Some day I hope to discover how a "filter" is anything more than a folder.  I'd hate to have to use the kind of project you create, that's *way* too fine-grained.

Comment: @Hans: Yes, I agree. For some reason Visual Studio calls it a filter, but it really seems more like a folder to me, and as far as I can tell, there is very little filtering capability with it (which is the reason for this question.I don't know if you were commenting on the tree structure or the Visual Studio environment with the "I'd hate" part, but what I described above is a simplified structure. The actual project has thousands of files, and it is nice to have them in folders.

Comment: I'll up that one, I'd hate to have to use a project with *thousands* of files more.  That's two orders of magnitude beyond reasonable.  How did you get into that pickle?

Comment: What is the "filter" supposed to do anyway?